# Convertir String en propiedad de una entidad c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
var query = (
                        from p in _context.ItemWarehouse
                        where filters.value==null || p.GetType().Name(filters.column)== filters.value
```

Tengo la siguiente consulta con linq , el nombre de la columna a filtrar en la entidad esta como string en "filters.column", necesito convertirlo en una propiedad de la entidad "p"

El error de la consulta es

```
Error   CS1955  No se puede usar como método el miembro 'MemberInfo.Name' no invocable.
```

como podria convertir a la propiedad? porfavor alguna sugerencia , gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from p in _context.ItemWarehouse
where filters.value == null || 
// Lo que se necesita es la propiedad así que se obtiene con el método
// GetProperty(name)
// Luego se necesita el valor de esa propiedad y se usa el método 
// GetValue(object)
p.GetType().GetProperty(filters.column).GetValue(p) == filters.value
```